# auth guard with firebase sdk

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I try to check if current user exists (logged in) or not and returning it in the auth guard.

```
  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user: firebase.User) => {
      if (user) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
  }
```

But I got this error:

> A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return
>   a value.

Looks like the return statements are not linked to the canActivate function.

Comment: You need to add `return` before `firebase` (and change the function signature to return `Observable<boolean>`).

Comment: thats the solution but not the why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your guard canActivate methods return type is boolean and you are not return any thing you are getting the error.

You can return a boolean to resolve this issue. But in your case I can see is your return type will be observable and inside the observable you want to return true or false.

So you change you guard t.

you need to do 2 thing as below

```
  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): : boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
     return firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user: firebase.User) => {
      if (user) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
  }
```

You need to check what is the return type of `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` normally these kind of methods returns observable. If that is the case then you need to change it to as below

```
  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): : boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
     return firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged().map((user: firebase.User) => {
      if (user) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
  }
```

Comment: thats it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`canActivate` method should return `Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean`
you should create a promise or observable from `onAuthStateChanged` callback:

```
 canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
              state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user: firebase.User) => {
        if (user) {
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          this.router.navigate([ '/login' ], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
          resolve(false);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```